# Configuring Campaign Measurement on Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracker

For some time I have been trying to configure Google Campaign Measurement in my android app. I have followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) and, after struggling with Google's documentation mess, arrived at the point where everything works as it should according to that tutorial. I receive the GAThread logcat message properly.

However, my Analytics panel receives no data, despite being paired with the Developer account. I think I may have a wrong idea of the whole process after following the tutorial, so please clarify:

1. I am following the first solution in the tutorial, with the already-implemented Receiver, which should send the data automatically. Do I need to have a Tracker configured for it anyway?
2. If I do need a tracker, which and where? It it enough to put a meta-data tag in my manifest like this:

   android:name = "com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
   android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
3. If it is not enough, which of the trackers defined [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#multiple-trackers) do I need in order to receive the data properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the latest Google Play Service 7.3, it provides more robust campaign tracking. You need to register both the campaign receiver and the campaign service in your AndoridManifest.xml as show in the [hello world example app](https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L47). You also need to configure at least one tracker and send at least one hit with it for campaign tracking to function correctly. To send hit it might be simpler to [enable auto activity tracking](http://tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true)) with tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true). Installation campaign will be send to all known trackers you use in your app.

Comment: How can I hit on a tracker first? The referrer data is hit right after the first boot, is it not? Or do you mean hitting on the Tracker ID once in general?

As for the all known trackers part, is defining a global, xml-based tracker in the manifest enough for that? Or do I need to initialize it in code?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you initialize the tracker, form code or from xml. You need to send actual hit to the tracker (like event or screen view). The campaign is received in the app at some point it time possibly significantly later then the first launch. Analytics will send the campaign information to all trackers used by the app earlier. If you send a hit to tracker that you have not used before the campaign will be send to that tracker as well. The order of receiving the installation broadcast and your app sending hit to the tracker is unimportant. In either case the campaign will be send.